# How do I change the color my Windows theme uses for text rendering?

Tags: fonts, windows-registry, color-theme

Does anyone know how I do this, maybe in the registry? After some failed attempts at some new themes, even after going back into the default windows theme, all of my fonts are completely washed out, I can't see anything against the usual white back pane of the windows. I'm on Windows 8 Pro x64

Comment: Sorry I should have said that before the edit. I'm on Windows 8 and MSFT has the horrible habit of changing their menus in every single OS release they do